# Mbed Cortex-m hardfault when sending data via TCP

Tags: tcp, mbed

I have a TCPSocket* object which holds a connection to a client. This object is passed to another object to send data back to the client:

```cpp
uint32_t count = 10;

char* message = new char[4];

message[0] = count & 0xff;

message[1] = (count >> 8) & 0xff;

message[2] = (count >> 16) & 0xff;

message[3] = (count >> 24) & 0xff;

client->send(&message, 4);
```

When this part of the program is called, the following appears on the serial line, and no data is received by the client:

```
    ++ MbedOS Fault Handler ++



                                                                                                          FaultType: HardFault



                                                                                                                              Context:

   R0   : 00000000

                  R1   : 10008000

                                 R2   : 00000004

                                                R3   : 2007C000

                                                               R4   : 10000914

                                                                              R5   : 00000000

                                                                                             R6   : 00000000

                                                                                                            R7   : 10004330

                                                                                                                           R8   : 10004320

       R9   : FFFFF435

                      R10  : 00000000

                                     R11  : 00000000

                                                    R12  : 00012AC1

                                                                   SP   : 10002AF0

                                                                                  LR   : 0000D1A1

                                                                                                 PC   : 00005938

                                                                                                                xPSR : 21000000

                                                                                                                               PSP  : 10002AD0

           MSP  : 10007FD8

                          CPUID: 412FC230

                                         HFSR : 40000000

                                                        MMFSR: 00000000

                                                                       BFSR : 00000082

                                                                                     UFSR : 00000000

                                                                                                     DFSR : 0000000A

                                                                                                                    AFSR : 00000000

                                                                                                                                   BFAR : 10008010

               Mode : Thread

                            Priv : Privileged

                                             Stack: PSP



                                                       -- MbedOS Fault Handler --







                                                                                 ++ MbedOS Error Info ++

                                                                                                        Error Status: 0x80FF013D Code: 317 Module: 255

                   Error Message: Fault exception

                                                 Location: 0xD337

                                                                 Error Value: 0x5938

                                                                                    Current Thread: main  Id: 0x10002B48 Entry: 0xD7D7 StackSize: 0x1000 StackMem: 0x10001B48 SP: 0x10007F88

                                                          For more info, visit: https://armmbed.github.io/mbedos-error/?error=0x80FF013D

     -- MbedOS Error Info --
```

Everything is in one thread so I cant see what could be causing this.

These are the relevant parts of the program:

main:

```cpp
// Network interface
EthernetInterface net;

TCPSocket listener; //listens for incoming connection requests
TCPSocket* client;

CommandProcessor commandProcessor(client);

int main() {

    int remaining;
    int rcount;
    char *p;
    char *buffer = new char[16];
    nsapi_size_or_error_t result;

    int n = net.set_network("192.168.1.103","255.255.255.0","192.168.1.2");
    pc.printf("\n Success? %d\n", n);
    net.connect();

    listener.open(&net);
    listener.bind(3045);

    listener.listen(1);

    client = listener.accept(NULL);
    client->set_timeout(1000);

    led1 = 1;

    while(1) {
        int remaining = 16;
        int rcount = 0;
        p = buffer;

        while (remaining > 0 && 0 < (result = client->recv(p, remaining))) {
            p += result;
            rcount += result;
            remaining -= result;
        }

        if (remaining == 0) //full message received
        {
            commandProcessor.process(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

CommandProcessor:

```cpp
CommandProcessor::CommandProcessor(TCPSocket* client)
{
    this->client = client;
}

void CommandProcessor::process(char* message)
{

    switch(message[0]) { //Command is first byte of message

        case 0x3: { 

            uint32_t count = 10 ;

            char* message = new char[4];

            message[0] = count & 0xff;
            message[1] = (count >> 8) & 0xff;
            message[2] = (count >> 16) & 0xff;
            message[3] = (count >> 24) & 0xff;

            client->send(message, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commandProcessor`'s `client` is `NULL` when you call `commandProcessor.process(buffer)`.

Why don’t you create an instance of `CommandProcessor` after you get a pointer to a socket from `accept()`.

```cpp
CommandProcessor* commandProcessor;

client = listener.accept(NULL);
commandProcessor = new CommandProcessor(client);

commandProcessor->process(buffer);
```

Alternatively, you can set `client` with a function like this.

```cpp
void CommandProcessor::setClient(TCPSocket* client) {
    this->client = client;
}
```

usage:

```cpp
client = listener.accept(NULL);
commandProcessor.setClient(client);
```

Comment: Oh, is that because when listener returns a new client, its address is different to the one that CommandProcessor has?

Comment: yes. you want to update the address or create an instance only after you have a client.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! A while back I did the "send" in main(), but found that it only worked for some integers. Can you explain why this might be? If you have a solution for this I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "it only worked for some integers". Can you update your question? Or maybe you better post it as a new question if it is not related to this hardfault problem?

Comment: I mean that the client (PC) would only receive certain integers (I changed count several times to test it out), and the rest of the time there would be no response and the program would crash. This leads me to believe that I may not be formatting the integers correctly for transmission.

Comment: just use ```uint8_t message[4]``` instead of ```char* message = new char[4]```. char may be signed.

Comment: Shouldn't that be on the heap at least? Otherwise message may be out of scope when the data is sent.